# How to test whether a row in an array matches a sequence, row-wise, in R

Tags: r, subset, apply

I have a vector, v3, that looks like this:

```
v3 <- matrix(c(1,1,3,3,2,2,
               2,3,1,2,3,1,
               3,2,2,1,1,3), ncol = 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    3    1    2
[4,]    3    2    1
[5,]    2    3    1
[6,]    2    1    3
```

I would like to examine rows for whether they are ascending or descending sequences. I tried this:
`v3[row(v3)[,1],]==(c(1,2,3)||c(3,2,1))`
but it produced:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

instead of

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE TRUE   TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You original code first calculated `(c(1,2,3)||c(3,2,1))` which returned TRUE and then your `==` operation looked for all the values in the matrix data.frame that were `1`'s. (You also falsified the output of the data.frame since that was the output style of a matrix object.)

Comment: I didn't falsify it, it was edited by David.  It was originally listed as a matrix.

Comment: But thanks @DWin for helping me debug what was actually happening there.

Comment: For the record, the data was not provided as an R object before my edit; I added a data.frame out of habit, but have changed it to a matrix to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
adtest <- function(v) rep((all(diff(v)>0)) | all(diff(v) < 0), length(v))
t(apply(v3, 1, adtest))

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I really like the should-be-gratuitous 'rep' command here.  The original question really should want a 1-dimensional object for a return value.